# How to you use Max and Min expression in Ms Access SQL?

Tags: sql, ms-access

[CrimeData Table for 12 months](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HgSHd.png)
[Crime Took place in Easternmost](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Guk6I.png)

I need to find the following:
Q.7 What type of Crime takes place in the …
(a) Easternmost ………………..
(b) Westernmost ………………..
(c) Northernmost………………..
(d) Southernmost………………..

I tried to find the crime took place in the Easternmost using the following SQL code
**SELECT Max(CrimeData.Easting) AS MaxOfEasting, CrimeData.Type
FROM CrimeData
GROUP BY CrimeData.Type;**
but I got more than one crime and also other Easting numbers. Can you please tell me if there are other good ways to find the solution.

Please see the attached pictures :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than using Max/Min, have a look at the TOP keyword in SQL. Some SQL might look like:

```
SELECT TOP 1 CD.*
FROM CrimeData CD
ORDER BY CD.Easting DESC;
```

Regards,

Comment: thank you, big help, just want to know how to put it if I am looking for Westernmost? since I only have Easting and Northing in CrimeData table and I need to find Southernmost and Westernmost. Kind regards

Comment: As the Westernmost is simply the least Easterly, just change the order by to `ORDER BY CD.Easting ASC;`.